# Simple onkeydown + length count

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple function here:

```
$('#input').keydown( function(e) {

    if( $(this).length === 8 ) { alert('We have a winner!'); }
    else { return false; }

});
```

It does not work. Why? Any help much appreciated.

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/BB7pS/)**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is it supposed to alert when someone has input a string which is 8 characters long?

Comment: In the end - this will add the class - which will display a tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to check the length of the value of `#input`, then you want:

```
$(this).val().length
```

Instead of `$(this).length`. You also may want to get rid of the `return false;` as that could prevent anything from being entered into the input field.

See an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BB7pS/22/).

On a separate note, this will only work when there are already 8 characters in the field, and another key is pressed. That may be the way you intended it, but I think you may want the `keyup` event instead.

Comment: Yep! That is correct - still though does not work :/ Not letting to type.

Comment: Works for me - what is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Pete - as mentioned in my answer, get rid of the `else` branch with `return false;` in it. the `return false` prevents the default behaviour of the input element, and nothing is written to it.

Comment: Alert goes off when you type in 9th character - keydown is not suitable here.

Comment: @Pete - I also said that in my answer... `keyup` is going to be a better event for you to use here.

Answer (score 3):

Try `keyUp` instead, and remove the `return false` branch:

```
$(document).ready( function(e){
    $('#input').keyup( function(e){
        if( $(this).val().length == 8 ) { alert('We have a winner!');}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('document').ready( function(e){

    $('#input').keydown( function(e){


        if( $(this).val().length === 8 ) { 
            alert('We have a winner!');
        }



    });
});
```

Use val() for first getting the value of the textbox on which the event is firing and then cal the length of the string.

Comment: Please note you have to get rid of the return false!! thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use .length in jquery on your wrapped set, it gives you the number of elements matched from your selector: http://api.jquery.com/length/. What you want is to get the length of the value of your input (.val().length ).